# .NET MessagingToolkit QRCode Issue

Tags: c#, .net, qr-code

I have been trying to put the value **"ddef04d8-7450-42d1-bc48-a94c3d6dae66**" in to a QR code using the  ".NET MessagingToolkit". The QR code generation process works fine. But when I actually scan the generated code the value comes as **"000000408-7450-4201-0048-094030600066"**. The characters are replaced with "0"s. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You're definitely setting `QRCodeEncodeMode = QRCodeEncoder.ENCODE_MODE.ALPHA_NUMERIC` or `BYTE`?

Comment: I have set it to ALPHA_NUMERIC. Is that a problem? If so what is the ENCODE_MODE I should use?

Comment: No, I thought maybe you'd set it to NUMERIC which wouldn't have worked. OK, that's not the problem then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's works for me

```
QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
encoder.QRCodeErrorCorrect = QRCodeEncoder.ERROR_CORRECTION.H;
encoder.QRCodeScale = 10;
Bitmap img = encoder.Encode("ddef04d8-7450-42d1-bc48-a94c3d6dae66");
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I had the same problem. The solution for me was Jijo's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

replace encoding settings from `ALPHA_NUMERIC` to `BYTE`

E.g. `QRCodeEncodeMode = QRCodeEncoder.ENCODE_MODE.BYTE`

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted. This was the only solution for me. "Alpha_numeric" certainly wasn't working.